# Display category name on featured image in wordpress excerpt

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails, excerpt

Helo.

I would like all my featured images on homepage, post page, search and archives pages to have the name of the post category printed on it. so people will easily know if the post is entertainment, tech or education without reading it already.

Please help

Comment: You can use `the_category( ' ' );` inside your loop to show category of post. For more detail read this [article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

Answer (score 1):

use `get_the_category()`

```
<?php
  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
     echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
   } 
?>
```

**Note:** It will return a list of categories if there are more than one category